# Is there a way to show a single employee with each of his projects using a query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables `Employees` and `Projects`.

Each employee can have multiple projects. Each project can have multiple employees working on it. So, the connection is many to many.

Foreign key constraints are used in third table `EmployeesProjects` which in Entity Framework is replaced with virtual properties `ICollection<Employee>` in entity `Project`, and `ICollection<Project>` in entity `Employee`.

I am searching for a way to return a selection in which employee data is joined to each of its projects data separately. So, if an employee has 3 projects the result will be 3 rows - each row should have data from the employee and a project of his.

I know how to do it in plain SQL, but i want to do it in base-first manner with Linq. Also, i don't want to use native query from inside Visual Studio.

So far, I have tried:

```
Select(emp => new { emp, emp.Projects })
```

but this should be used with `foreach` for `emp.Projects` to give me what I need, while I need to foreach the result.

I played with join but `emp` has no projectId nor `emp.Projects` can expose `employeeId` property (it is obvious but in my desperation I tried with `pr.Employees.FirstOrDefault()` and other ways to expose `EmployeeID`).

I am new to Entity Framework and I wonder if it is possible something that looks so simple at first glance, to be done through the vehicle of LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a case for `.SelectMany()`:

```
var tuples = employees.SelectMany(employee => employee.Projects.Select(project =>
    new {employee, project}
));
```

or implicitly in inline linq:

```
var tuples = 
    from employee in employees
    from project in employee.Projects
    select new {employee, project};
```

Comment: SelectMany(employee => employee.Projects.Select(project =>
    new {employee, project} did the trick, though it was the nested use of select that  was escaping me. Thanks :)